# Downloading ubuntu 12.04 LTS on MacBook Pro OSX

Tags: software-center

I am trying to download Ubuntu on my computer, but whenever I operate the ubuntu it says the following disk images couldn't be opened.

My question is do I need some kind of application to operate Ubuntu?

Please help me to download Ubuntu on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome or Firefox to download. Safari tries to open files it downloads. You don't open the file that you download. You need to burn it to a DVD and then boot from that.